# Sending qx.io.request.Xhr request with array in request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, qooxdoo

According to [documentation](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.io.request.AbstractRequest~requestData), requestData can handle ArrayBuffer parameter. However when I try this:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(16); 
var ar = new Uint8Array(buf); 
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) 
    ar[i] = i * 10; 
request = new qx.io.request.Xhr(); 
request.setUrl(url); 
request.setRequestData(buf); 
request.send();
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: params must be either string or object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not tried it, but probably you have to `request.setMethod('POST');` as seen in https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/test/bom/request/SimpleXhr.js#L337

Comment: Thanks, Tobi, that solves it! Can you please post it as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the method to POST

```
request.setMethod('POST');
```

before calling `request.send()`. So your example would look like this:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(16); 
var ar = new Uint8Array(buf); 
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    ar[i] = i * 10; 
}
request = new qx.io.request.Xhr().set({
    url: url,
    requestData: buf,
    method: 'POST'
}).send();
```

see also https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/test/bom/request/SimpleXhr.js#L337